# Regex for words separated by ".-_" including at least a letter

Tags: regex

This is for validating usernames on my system.

Every username can include these symbols ".-_", but the words separated by the mentioned symbols cannot be digits only.

An example would be

Invalid:

```
123.as-as123
123.AS-aS123
```

Valid:

```
a123.as-as123
A123.AS-aS123
```

Comment: Can your username not contain any of those symbols? or it has to contain all of them? And can any of those symbols come back to back?

Comment: @RohitJain It can be any of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will work, if I understand your requirements correctly:

```
/^(?:[a-z0-9]*[a-z][a-z0-9]*[.\-_])*[a-z0-9]*[a-z][a-z0-9]*$/i
```

It matches zero or more groups of letters/numbers ending with `.`,`-`, or `_` and requiring at least one letter.  Then it matches a final group of letters/numbers, requiring at least one letter.

It is case insensitive (that is what the `i` at the end does), so it will match uppercase as well.  (This syntax works at least in Perl and PHP.  In other languages, you might have to apply this option in a slightly different way, but case insensitive is always available).

One might be tempted to shorten it like this:

```
/^(?:[a-z0-9]*[a-z][a-z0-9]*[.\-_]?)+$/i
```

However, that is less desirable, because making the `[.\-_]` optional gives it too much flexibility in the ways it can try to match.  It will probably have to run through a huge number of cases on a pattern that fails.

Comment: I think I should have mentioned in the question, it can include uppercase letters as well. I'll update the question. The answer is correct though. But please include uppercase letters as well.

Comment: @Peymankh, the `/i` switch that I used allows uppercase as well.

Comment: Hmm just tried this out of curiosity, but both (long and shorter) regex don't work for me with the given strings.

Comment: @Simon, thanks, there was a dumb mistake: I forgot to escape `-` in the character class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these 4 regex to check.

```
^([0-9]*?)[\.\-\_]         // Check if number is present between start and symbols
[\.\-\_]([0-9]*?)[\.\-\_]  // Check if number is present between these symbols
[\.\-\_]([0-9]*)$          // Check if number is present between these symbols and eol
^([0-9]+)$                 // Check only if number is present
```

if output of any of these is ne '', print invalid else valid.